# how to remove file not found error in angular js

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, ionic-framework, angular-ui-router

I am trying to handle exception  in angular js .I am able to handle in one scenario  but on scenario it fail to handle why ?

Actually when anything is undefined it is catch my $exceptionHandler.But when file is not found it is not catch by $exceptionHandler
why

Example 
plunker
http://plnkr.co/edit/mm4Uix8XXVrkhexW15vR?p=preview

**case 1**

when I hit this

```
$http.get("default.json").then(successcallback, errorcallback);
```

on success             `alert(data.hhh.getname()); it is undefined which is catch by`$exceptionHandler and store in array .Here is the output[image]

**case 2**
But when I change the name of file default.son to defaul.json it is not catch by $exceptionHandler why ?
and it show 404 error on console.can we catch this error and print on console ? can we catch this error ..?

Actually I don't want to get this error [image]

how to handle this error ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See documentation for [$exceptionHandler](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$exceptionHandler). Note the part:

> Note, that code executed in event-listeners (even those registered using jqLite's on/bind methods) does not delegate exceptions to the $exceptionHandler (unless executed during a digest).

What this means is that `$exceptionHandler` catches uncaught exception thrown from a [digest cycle](http://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-angulars-apply-digest/). However if you actually click on the line where the 404 is thrown, you should notice that it's thrown by XHR, outside of Angular's [$apply](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$apply), therefore `$exceptionHandler` is not in a scope outside of it to catch it. On the other hand, your `data.hhh.getname()` is in a [$q](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q) success callback, which is wrapped in an [$apply](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$apply), so it was caught by `$exeptionHandler`.

**EDIT**
Actually the [article I linked for digest cycle](http://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-angulars-apply-digest/) explains this better.

> Keep in mind that you should always use the version of $apply() that accepts a function argument. This is because when you pass a function to $apply(), the function call is wrapped inside a try...catch block, and any exceptions that occur will be passed to the $exceptionHandler service.

It's more than just a digest cycle, it needs to be inside [$apply](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$apply)'s scope. Otherwise Angular won't have an opportunity to put `try ... catch` block anywhere to catch exceptions and pass it to `$exceptionHandler`.

**EDIT** Upon closer inspection, the 404 that you see in console is not even an exception. It's logged to `console.error` by [XHR](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest), which is a native API. So what you see in console will have to stay and cannot be caught. However notice that you can always check `$http` failures in its failure callback, so you can inject `$exceptionHandler` (which I see you have configured on your own) and manually log with it. eg.

```
responseError: function(error){
    $exceptionHandler(new Error(
            error.config.method + ' ' +
            error.config.url + ' ' +
            error.status +' ' +
            '(' + error.statusText + ')'
    )); 
    return $q.reject(error);
}
```

See [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/AgLG6CkZI9OVj7tgh8JA?p=preview)

Comment: Thanks for answering  so how to catch this exception

Comment: you did not use $apply function as use told that you it is out of scope

Comment: @Shruti see my explanation in edits. 1. the 404 error you see in console is NOT an exception. It was simply logged to `console.log` by your browser. It cannot be caught. 2. even if it was an exception, `$apply` needs to be applied by AngularJS. It's not something you can catch on your side if it's an exception thrown from a async third-party library called by AngularJS. 3. use of `$apply` is recommended for your own code. Again, if AngularJS called a third-party library, then AngularJS has to handle it.